# Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available in Openwrt Embedded Device

Tags: java, embedded, java-11, openwrt, adoptopenjdk

I am using a distro based on OpenWRT 21, running on an ARM Cortex A9 with NEON architecture (i.MX6). When I try to run a Java application with a .jar extension, I encounter the following error: `Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available`. The default Java version that comes with the distro is:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

Moreover, when I test the same application on my x86 PC running Ubuntu 22.04, I don't encounter this error. The Java version on this system is:

```
openjdk version "11.0.20.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The application is distributed directly in a JAR format, and I have no expertise in Java. I tried copying the `java.security` file directly from the working version on Ubuntu to the OpenWRT system, but as expected, it didn’t work.

Updating the Java version might be an option, but it seems quite hard, and moreover, it appears to work on another device with the same main version. I can’t think of any other solutions and feel quite stuck. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.